# Sybase column rename error

Tags: sap-ase

Could not rename a column in a Sybase 15 table. I am getting the below error. Please help. What am I missing?

```
Incorrect syntax near 'NAME1'.


CREATE TABLE TEST1 (NAME1 VARCHAR(20) NULL, NAME2 VARCHAR(20) NULL)
GO
ALTER TABLE TEST1 RENAME NAME1 TO FIRST_NAME
GO
```

Referring http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1270/html/iqref/BABCGFHG.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have tagged Sybase ASE but your link points to Sybase IQ

Here is how you do in ASE

```
sp_rename 'TEST1.NAME1', 'FIRST_NAME'
```

Comment: I wanted it in ASE. Thank you.